# Is character encoding different between HTTP:// and FILE:// protocols?

Tags: flash, http, character-encoding, protocols, local

I'm trying to load some multilingual content in Flash.

Locally, everything seems to run fine.

- My Local file is on an HTML page, making calls to external content served as an XML document.
- The content contains Chinese characters enclosed in CDATA tags.
- Flash displays the Chinese characters correctly (on device fonts).

However, when hosted on the web server (embedded in a JSP page), it doesn't work:

- The SWF is displayed, and loads the content.
- The content contains the same data, and traces of the raw content in Flash indicates that it is indeed the same Chinese symbol as shown in the local environment.
- Flash displays long numbers (looks like 4 hex numbers per Chinese character) instead of the Chinese character, this is incorrect!

So I'm curious if there is a difference in the way Flash interprets the XML data if the SWF is hosted over a local environment "file://..." or a web server "http://...".

Anyone else ever ran into the same problem? I'm searching through Character encoding, unicode, UTF-8, but it doesn't make sense that the local version works but the web-server doesn't. Hmm...

--EDIT--

**Some examples:**

- アリコ became 65E5672C751F547D
- ネクスティア became 30CD30AF30B930C630A330A2
- アフラック became 30A230D530E930C330AF

Comment: Since the traces are the same in both cases, doesn't that rule out a problem outside of flash? How are you displaying it, show some code!

Comment: company code, can't insert it here. But the traces are identical only to an extent. It looks like when it converts the XML to String (for the tags we pull the data from), those traces indicate that the Chinese symbols are changed to numbers on the web-version (but not the local-version). Wish I could paste something to clarify, but sorry!

Comment: Hmm no, well when I open it up in a Developer inspector tools, the response actually displays the Chinese characters (no numbers, no unicodes, just the symbols themselves.) So I'm not too sure if we're supposed to pre-encode them on the server-side to unicode first? Our content is multilingual though, so it sounds like we would need to unicode EVERYTHING, not sure that is the correct approach though.

Comment: Added 3 examples of the conversion issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tool to examine the HTTP headers sent from the server. Is the mime type correct?

You do have encoding set properly in the XML, don't you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

-- EDIT

How about `System.useCodepage = true;`? It's not a silver bullet though.

Comment: that may be the reason why actually. Its not included in our dynamically created XML.

Comment: If there is no encoding specified in the XML then UTF-8 is the default. So that might explain why the local file works fine, if the XML is actually UTF-8 encoded. However, when delivering XML over an HTTP connection, the HTTP `Content-Type` header may take priority depending on its value, even if the XML specifies an encoding, so if there is a mismatch, the XML won't be parsed correctly.

Comment: Hmm alright. I'll place the above XML declaration on top of also having the HTTP headers set as "Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8". Maybe Flash isn't smart enough to realize the headers are specifying that it is UTF-8!

Comment: It looks more messed up when I put `System.useCodepage = true`, some odd looking latin letter with accents shows up when it's enabled.